# Is there anyway to make a variable "partially protected"?

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, protected

I have the following class hierarchy

```
 public class Third : Second
{
}

public class Second : First
{
}

public class First
{
     private int MyVariable;
}
```

if i want to access MyVariable from Second and Third, I could make MyVariable protected but what if i want to access from Second but NOT Third.  Is that possible?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: Only if you hide it using the `new` keyword. Anyway that's not the best object oriented practice I have seen to be honest.

Comment: Have you considered composition to be an option?

Comment: Consider making your First class abstract and then only implementing MyVariable in the classes that need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not thinking about this in an object-oriented manner.

You state that every `Third` is a `Second`. But you want every `Second` to have access to the variable, but you don't want any `Third` to have access.

But if `Third` does not have access, then it is not a `Second`!

Comment: Then how do you explain my example?

Comment: I can't yet. I'll have to think about it. Private implementation details need not be inherited in order for polymorphism to work.

Comment: You're mis-applying the Liskov Substitution Principle, which is "if q(x) is a fact about all objects x of type Base then q(y) should be a fact about all objects y of type Derived". You are proposing for the predicate q(z) "z has access to the field". But the predicate has to be a predicate about **objects**! That predicate is about **a region of source code**, not about **an object generated at runtime**.

Comment: @EricLippert: nag, nag, nag. :-)

Comment: Not violating LSP means Eric's solutions won't make things hard on people who are using `First` while unaware of the existence of `Second` and `Third`.  That is, it is unlikely to be the cause of bugs in classes which consume instances of `First`.  They strike me as great solutions to a problem most people (likely including the OP) don't usually have.

Answer (score 13):

> If I want to access `MyVariable` from `Second` and `Third` I could make `MyVariable` protected. What if I want to access from `Second` but NOT `Third`. Is that possible?

Yes! Here's one technique:

```
class First
{
    private int myVariable;
    public class Second : First
    {
        public Second() { myVariable = 123; } // Legal!
    }
}

class Third : First.Second
{
    public Third() { myVariable = 456; } // Illegal!
}
```

Here's another:

```
// Alpha.DLL
public class First 
{ 
    internal int myVariable;
}
public class Second : First
{
    public Second() { myVariable = 123; } // Legal!
}

// Bravo.DLL
class Third : Second
{
    public Third() { myVariable = 456; } // Illegal!
}
```